# Recurrence relation $a_r+6a_{r-1}+9a_{r-2}=3$, then find $a_{20}$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

> Consider the recurrence relation $a_r+6a_{r-1}+9a_{r-2}=3$, given that $a_0=0, a_1=1$. Let $a_{20}=x\times10^9$, then the value of $x$ is______ .

---

My attempt:

$a_r=3-6a_{r-1}-9a_{r-2}$

I calculated manually, I get $a_{20}=-6465079410=-6.46\times10^9$, so $x=-6.46$

> Can you explain in formal way, please?

Comment: Did you try the method of generating functions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n z^n$. Multiplying both sides of the recurrence by $z^n$ and summing over $n$ yields
$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty a_n z^n +6\sum_{n=2}^\infty a_{n-1}z^n +9\sum_{n=2}^\infty a_{n-2}z^n = 3\sum_{n=2}^\infty z^n, $$
or
$$f(z)-(a_0+a_1z)+6z(f(z)-a_0) + 9z^2f(z)=\frac{3z^2}{1-z}. $$ Substituting $a_0$ and $a_1$ and isolating $f(z)$, we have $$f(z)(1+6z+9z^2) = \frac{3z^2}{1-z}+z, $$
and hence
$$f(z) = \frac z{(1+3z)^2}+\frac{3z^2}{(1-z)(1+3z)^2}. $$ Partial fraction decomposition yields
$$f(z) = \frac3{16}\left(\frac1{1-z}\right)-\frac5{48}\left(\frac1{1+3z}\right)-\frac1{12}\left(\frac1{(1+3z)^2}\right). $$
Manipulating the geometric series $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty z^n=\frac1{1-z} $$ we find that $$f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac3{16}z^n - \sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac5{48}(-3)^n z^n-\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac1{12}(n+1)(-3)^nz^n.$$
Simplifying, we have
$$f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac3{16}-\frac5{48}(-1)^n3^{n}-\frac1{12}(n+1)(-1)^n3^{n} \right)z^n, $$
and so we conclude that $$a_n=\frac3{16}-\frac5{48}(-1)^n3^{n}-\frac1{12}(n+1)(-1)^n3^{n}. $$
In particular,
$$a_{20} = \frac{3}{16}-\frac{5}{48} (-1)^{20} 3^{20}-\frac{21}{12} (-1)^{20} 3^{20}=-6465079410. $$

Comment: So, $a_{20}=-944337441.75$?

Comment: No, $a_{20} = -6465079410$, so the value given in the question is correct.

Comment: There seems to be a mistake in the third equation, where the right most term $7z$ should be $z$.  Note that $6z a_0 = 0$ because $a_0=0$.

Comment: Thanks @svsring, I've corrected the error.

Comment: Thanks for nice explanation.

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

Let $a_n=Ab_n+B$

$$Ab_n+B+6(Ab_{n-1}+B)+9(Ab_{n-2}+B)=3$$

$$A(b_n+6b_{n-1}+9b_{n-2})+B(1+6+9)-3=0$$

Set $B(1+6+9)-3=0\iff B=?$

and use [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#Solving) on $$b_n+6b_{n-1}+9b_{n-2}=0$$

Comment: This ain't a formal solution.

Answer (score 1):

To make your life easier, work with difference equations: write the rxpression for the previous term and subtract. You get rid of the annoying constant term and set $b_n =a_n -a_{n-1}$. Then use GF or characteristic equation.

Answer (score 1):

If you work out the answer manually, you get $x=-6.46$. You could try the method of generating functions to obtain a formula.